# Extra White Space showing on right side of website in chrome browser but working fine on firefox browser

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

My website is showing extra white space on right space on google chrome browser. It's working fine on firefox browser. I have also additional CSS code (currently disabled as it's not working). Please check my website and help me!!

I have also added screenshot of chrome browser & firefox browser.
[image: Screenshot]

```css
blockquote,body,dd,dl,dt,fieldset,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,html,iframe,legend,li,ol,p,pre,textarea,ul{margin:0;padding:0;border:0}html{font-family:sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}main{display:block}progress{vertical-align:baseline}html{box-sizing:border-box}*,::after,::before{box-sizing:inherit}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0}[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-moz-focus-inner{border-style:none;padding:0}:-moz-focusring{outline:1px dotted ButtonText}body,button,input,select,textarea{font-family:-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";font-weight:400;text-transform:none;font-size:17px;line-height:1.5}p{margin-bottom:1.5em}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;font-style:inherit;font-weight:inherit}pre{background:rgba(0,0,0,.05);font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:normal;margin-bottom:1.5em;padding:20px;overflow:auto;max-width:100%}blockquote{border-left:5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);padding:20px;font-size:1.2em;font-style:italic;margin:0 0 1.5em;position:relative}blockquote p:last-child{margin:0}table,td,th{border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1)}table{border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:0;border-width:1px 0 0 1px;margin:0 0 1.5em;width:100%}td,th{padding:8px}th{border-width:0 1px 1px 0}td{border-width:0 1px 1px 0}hr{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);border:0;height:1px;margin-bottom:40px;margin-top:40px}fieldset{padding:0;border:0;min-width:inherit}fieldset legend{padding:0;margin-bottom:1.5em}h1{font-size:42px;margin-bottom:20px;line-height:1.2em;font-weight:400;text-transform:none}h2{font-size:35px;margin-bottom:20px;line-height:1.2em;font-weight:400;text-transform:none}h3{font-size:29px;margin-bottom:20px;line-height:1.2em;font-weight:400;text-transform:none}h4{font-size:24px}h5{font-size:20px}h4,h5,h6{margin-bottom:20px}ol,ul{margin:0 0 1.5em 3em}ul{list-style:disc}ol{list-style:decimal}li>ol,li>ul{margin-bottom:0;margin-left:1.5em}dt{font-weight:700}dd{margin:0 1.5em 1.5em}b,strong{font-weight:700}cite,dfn,em,i{font-style:italic}address{margin:0 0 1.5em}code,kbd,tt,var{font:15px Monaco,Consolas,"Andale Mono","DejaVu Sans Mono",monospace}abbr,acronym{border-bottom:1px dotted #666;cursor:help}ins,mark{text-decoration:none}sub,sup{font-size:75%;height:0;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{bottom:1ex}sub{top:.5ex}small{font-size:75%}big{font-size:125%}figure{margin:0}table{margin:0 0 1.5em;width:100%}th{font-weight:700}img{height:auto;max-width:100%}button,input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{background:#55555e;color:#fff;border:1px solid transparent;cursor:pointer;-webkit-appearance:button;padding:10px 20px}input[type=email],input[type=number],input[type=password],input[type=search],input[type=tel],input[type=text],input[type=url],select,textarea{border:1px solid;border-radius:0;padding:10px 15px;max-width:100%}textarea{width:100%}a,button,input{transition:color .1s ease-in-out,background-color .1s ease-in-out}a,a:focus,a:hover,a:visited{text-decoration:none}.button,.wp-block-button .wp-block-button__link{padding:10px 20px;display:inline-block}.wp-block-button .wp-block-button__link{font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}.using-mouse :focus{outline:0}.using-mouse ::-moz-focus-inner{border:0}.alignleft{float:left;margin-right:1.5em}.alignright{float:right;margin-left:1.5em}.aligncenter{clear:both;display:block;margin:0 auto}.size-auto,.size-full,.size-large,.size-medium,.size-thumbnail{max-width:100%;height:auto}.no-sidebar .entry-content .alignfull{margin-left:calc(-100vw / 2 + 100% / 2);margin-right:calc(-100vw / 2 + 100% / 2);max-width:100vw;width:auto}.screen-reader-text{border:0;clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);-webkit-clip-path:inset(50%);clip-path:inset(50%);height:1px;margin:-1px;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute!important;width:1px;word-wrap:normal!important}.screen-reader-text:focus{background-color:#f1f1f1;border-radius:3px;box-shadow:0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);clip:auto!important;-webkit-clip-path:none;clip-path:none;color:#21759b;display:block;font-size:.875rem;font-weight:700;height:auto;left:5px;line-height:normal;padding:15px 23px 14px;text-decoration:none;top:5px;width:auto;z-index:100000}#primary[tabindex="-1"]:focus{outline:0}.main-navigation{z-index:100;padding:0;clear:both;display:block}.main-navigation a{display:block;text-decoration:none;font-weight:400;text-transform:none;font-size:15px}.main-navigation ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding-left:0}.main-navigation .main-nav ul li a{padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;line-height:60px}.inside-navigation{position:relative}.main-navigation .inside-navigation{display:flex;align-items:center;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:space-between}.main-navigation .main-nav>ul{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;align-items:center}.main-navigation li{position:relative}.main-navigation .menu-bar-items{display:flex;align-items:center;font-size:15px}.main-navigation .menu-bar-items a{color:inherit}.main-navigation .menu-bar-item{position:relative}.main-navigation .menu-bar-item.search-item{z-index:20}.main-navigation .menu-bar-item>a{padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;line-height:60px}.sidebar .main-navigation .main-nav{flex-basis:100%}.sidebar .main-navigation .main-nav>ul{flex-direction:column}.sidebar .main-navigation .menu-bar-items{margin:0 auto}.sidebar .main-navigation .menu-bar-items .search-item{order:10}.nav-align-center .inside-navigation{justify-content:center}.nav-align-center .main-nav>ul{justify-content:center}.nav-align-right .inside-navigation{justify-content:flex-end}.main-navigation ul ul{display:block;box-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);float:left;position:absolute;left:-99999px;opacity:0;z-index:99999;width:200px;text-align:left;top:auto;transition:opacity 80ms linear;transition-delay:0s;pointer-events:none;height:0;overflow:hidden}.main-navigation ul ul a{display:block}.main-navigation ul ul li{width:100%}.main-navigation .main-nav ul ul li a{line-height:normal;padding:10px 20px;font-size:14px}.main-navigation .main-nav ul li.menu-item-has-children>a{padding-right:0;position:relative}.main-navigation.sub-menu-left .sub-menu{right:0}.main-navigation:not(.toggled) ul li.sfHover>ul,.main-navigation:not(.toggled) ul li:hover>ul{left:auto;opacity:1;transition-delay:150ms;pointer-events:auto;height:auto;overflow:visible}.main-navigation:not(.toggled) ul ul li.sfHover>ul,.main-navigation:not(.toggled) ul ul li:hover>ul{left:100%;top:0}.main-navigation.sub-menu-left:not(.toggled) ul ul li.sfHover>ul,.main-navigation.sub-menu-left:not(.toggled) ul ul li:hover>ul{right:100%;left:auto}.nav-float-right .main-navigation ul ul ul{top:0}.menu-item-has-children .dropdown-menu-toggle{display:inline-block;height:100%;clear:both;padding-right:20px;padding-left:10px}.menu-item-has-children ul .dropdown-menu-toggle{padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-top:-10px}.sidebar .menu-item-has-children .dropdown-menu-toggle,nav ul ul .menu-item-has-children .dropdown-menu-toggle{float:right}.widget-area .main-navigation li{float:none;display:block;width:100%;padding:0;margin:0}.sidebar .main-navigation.sub-menu-right ul li.sfHover ul,.sidebar .main-navigation.sub-menu-right ul li:hover ul{top:0;left:100%}.sidebar .main-navigation.sub-menu-left ul li.sfHover ul,.sidebar .main-navigation.sub-menu-left ul li:hover ul{top:0;right:100%}.site-main .comment-navigation,.site-main .post-navigation,.site-main .posts-navigation{margin:0 0 2em;overflow:hidden}.site-main .post-navigation{margin-bottom:0}.paging-navigation .nav-next,.paging-navigation .nav-previous{display:none}.paging-navigation .nav-links>*{padding:0 5px}.paging-navigation .nav-links .current{font-weight:700}.nav-links>:first-child{padding-left:0}.site-header{position:relative}.inside-header{padding:20px 40px}.main-title{margin:0;font-size:25px;line-height:1.2em;word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:700;text-transform:none}.site-description{margin:0;line-height:1.5;font-weight:400;text-transform:none;font-size:15px}.site-logo{display:inline-block;max-width:100%}.site-header .header-image{vertical-align:middle}.inside-header{display:flex;align-items:center}.header-widget{margin-left:auto}.header-widget p:last-child{margin-bottom:0}.nav-float-right .header-widget{margin-left:20px}.nav-float-right #site-navigation{margin-left:auto}.nav-float-left #site-navigation{margin-right:auto;order:-10}.nav-float-left .header-widget{margin-left:0;margin-right:20px;order:-15}.header-aligned-center:not([class*=nav-float-]) .inside-header{justify-content:center;flex-direction:column;text-align:center}.header-aligned-center:not([class*=nav-float-]) .header-widget{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.header-aligned-center:not([class*=nav-float-]) .inside-header>:not(:first-child){margin-top:1em}.header-aligned-right:not([class*=nav-float-]) .inside-header{justify-content:flex-end}.header-aligned-right:not([class*=nav-float-]) .header-widget{margin-right:auto;margin-left:0;order:-10}.site-branding-container{display:inline-flex;align-items:center;text-align:left;flex-shrink:0}.site-branding-container .site-logo{margin-right:1em}.sticky{display:block}.entry-header .gp-icon,.posted-on .updated{display:none}.byline,.entry-header .cat-links,.entry-header .comments-link,.entry-header .tags-links,.group-blog .byline,.single .byline{display:inline}footer.entry-meta .byline,footer.entry-meta .posted-on{display:block}.entry-content:not(:first-child),.entry-summary:not(:first-child),.page-content:not(:first-child){margin-top:2em}.page-links{clear:both;margin:0 0 1.5em}.archive .format-aside .entry-header,.archive .format-status .entry-header,.archive .format-status .entry-meta,.archive .format-status .entry-title,.blog .format-aside .entry-header,.blog .format-status .entry-header,.blog .format-status .entry-meta,.blog .format-status .entry-title{display:none}.archive .format-aside .entry-content,.archive .format-status .entry-content,.blog .format-aside .entry-content,.blog .format-status .entry-content{margin-top:0}.archive .format-status .entry-content p:last-child,.blog .format-status .entry-content p:last-child{margin-bottom:0}.entry-header,.site-content{word-wrap:break-word}.entry-title{margin-bottom:0}.author .page-header .page-title{display:flex;align-items:center}.author .page-header .avatar{margin-right:20px}.page-header .author-info>:last-child,.page-header>:last-child{margin-bottom:0}.entry-meta{font-size:85%;margin-top:.5em;line-height:1.5}footer.entry-meta{margin-top:2em}.cat-links,.comments-link,.tags-links{display:block}.entry-content>p:last-child,.entry-summary>p:last-child,.page-content>p:last-child,.read-more-container,.taxonomy-description p:last-child{margin-bottom:0}.wp-caption{margin-bottom:1.5em;max-width:100%;position:relative}.wp-caption img[class*=wp-image-]{display:block;margin:0 auto 0;max-width:100%}.wp-caption .wp-caption-text{font-size:75%;padding-top:5px;opacity:.8}.wp-caption img{position:relative;vertical-align:bottom}.wp-block-image figcaption{font-size:13px;text-align:center}.wp-block-gallery,ul.blocks-gallery-grid{margin-left:0}.wp-block-gallery .blocks-gallery-image figcaption,.wp-block-gallery .blocks-gallery-item figcaption{background:rgba(255,255,255,.7);color:#000;padding:10px;box-sizing:border-box}.gallery{margin-bottom:1.5em}.gallery-item{display:inline-block;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:100%}.gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item{max-width:50%}.gallery-columns-3 .gallery-item{max-width:33.33%}.gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item{max-width:25%}.gallery-columns-5 .gallery-item{max-width:20%}.gallery-columns-6 .gallery-item{max-width:16.66%}.gallery-columns-7 .gallery-item{max-width:14.28%}.gallery-columns-8 .gallery-item{max-width:12.5%}.gallery-columns-9 .gallery-item{max-width:11.11%}.gallery-caption{display:block}.site-main .gallery{margin-bottom:1.5em}.gallery-item img{vertical-align:bottom}.gallery-icon{padding:5px}embed,iframe,object{max-width:100%}.widget-area .widget{padding:40px}.widget select{max-width:100%}.footer-widgets .widget :last-child,.sidebar .widget :last-child{margin-bottom:0}.widget-title{margin-bottom:30px;font-size:20px;line-height:1.5;font-weight:400;text-transform:none}.widget ol,.widget ul{margin:0}.widget .search-field{width:100%}.widget .search-form{display:flex}.widget .search-form button.search-submit{font-size:15px}.footer-widgets .widget{margin-bottom:30px}.footer-widgets .widget:last-child,.sidebar .widget:last-child{margin-bottom:0}.widget ul li{list-style-type:none;position:relative;margin-bottom:.5em}.widget ul li ul{margin-left:1em;margin-top:.5em}.wp-calendar-table{table-layout:fixed}.site-content{display:flex}.grid-container{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;max-width:1200px}.page-header,.sidebar .widget,.site-main>*{margin-bottom:20px}.both-left .inside-left-sidebar,.both-right .inside-left-sidebar{margin-right:10px}.both-left .inside-right-sidebar,.both-right .inside-right-sidebar{margin-left:10px}.one-container.both-right .site-main,.one-container.right-sidebar .site-main{margin-right:40px}.one-container.both-left .site-main,.one-container.left-sidebar .site-main{margin-left:40px}.one-container.both-sidebars .site-main{margin:0 40px 0 40px}.one-container.archive .post:not(:last-child),.one-container.blog .post:not(:last-child){padding-bottom:40px}.one-container .site-content{padding:40px}.separate-containers .comments-area,.separate-containers .inside-article,.separate-containers .page-header,.separate-containers .paging-navigation{padding:40px}.separate-containers .site-main{margin:20px}.separate-containers.no-sidebar .site-main{margin-left:0;margin-right:0}.separate-containers.both-right .site-main,.separate-containers.right-sidebar .site-main{margin-left:0}.separate-containers.both-left .site-main,.separate-containers.left-sidebar .site-main{margin-right:0}.separate-containers .inside-left-sidebar,.separate-containers .inside-right-sidebar{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px}.inside-page-header{padding:40px}.widget-area .main-navigation{margin-bottom:20px}.one-container .site-main>:last-child,.separate-containers .site-main>:last-child{margin-bottom:0}.full-width-content .container.grid-container{max-width:100%}.full-width-content.no-sidebar.separate-containers .site-main{margin:0}.full-width-content.one-container .site-content,.full-width-content.separate-containers .inside-article{padding:0}.full-width-content .entry-content .alignwide{margin-left:0;width:auto;max-width:unset}.contained-content.one-container .site-content,.contained-content.separate-containers .inside-article{padding:0}.sidebar .grid-container{max-width:100%;width:100%}.both-left .is-left-sidebar,.both-sidebars .is-left-sidebar,.left-sidebar .sidebar{order:-10}.both-left .is-right-sidebar{order:-5}.both-right .is-left-sidebar{order:5}.both-right .is-right-sidebar,.both-sidebars .is-right-sidebar{order:10}.inside-site-info{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;padding:20px 40px}.site-info{text-align:center;font-size:15px}.post-image:not(:first-child){margin-top:2em}.featured-image{line-height:0}.separate-containers .featured-image{margin-top:20px}.separate-containers .inside-article>.featured-image{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:2em}.one-container .inside-article>.featured-image{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:2em}.gp-icon{display:inline-flex;align-self:center}.gp-icon svg{height:1em;width:1em;top:.125em;position:relative;fill:currentColor}.close-search .icon-search svg:nth-child(1),.icon-menu-bars svg:nth-child(2),.icon-search svg:nth-child(2),.toggled .icon-menu-bars svg:nth-child(1){display:none}.close-search .icon-search svg:nth-child(2),.toggled .icon-menu-bars svg:nth-child(2){display:block}.entry-meta .gp-icon{margin-right:.6em;opacity:.7}nav.toggled .icon-arrow-left svg{transform:rotate(-90deg)}nav.toggled .icon-arrow-right svg{transform:rotate(90deg)}nav.toggled .sfHover>a>.dropdown-menu-toggle .gp-icon svg{transform:rotate(180deg)}nav.toggled .sfHover>a>.dropdown-menu-toggle .gp-icon.icon-arrow-left svg{transform:rotate(-270deg)}nav.toggled .sfHover>a>.dropdown-menu-toggle .gp-icon.icon-arrow-right svg{transform:rotate(270deg)}.container.grid-container{width:auto}.menu-toggle,.mobile-bar-items,.sidebar-nav-mobile{display:none}.menu-toggle{padding:0 20px;line-height:60px;margin:0;font-weight:400;text-transform:none;font-size:15px;cursor:pointer}.menu-toggle .mobile-menu{padding-left:3px}.menu-toggle .gp-icon+.mobile-menu{padding-left:9px}.menu-toggle .mobile-menu:empty{display:none}button.menu-toggle{background-color:transparent;flex-grow:1;border:0;text-align:center}button.menu-toggle:active,button.menu-toggle:focus,button.menu-toggle:hover{background-color:transparent}.has-menu-bar-items button.menu-toggle{flex-grow:0}nav.toggled ul ul.sub-menu{width:100%}.toggled .menu-item-has-children .dropdown-menu-toggle{padding-left:20px}.main-navigation.toggled .main-nav{flex-basis:100%;order:3}.main-navigation.toggled .main-nav>ul{display:block}.main-navigation.toggled .main-nav li{width:100%;text-align:left}.main-navigation.toggled .main-nav ul ul{transition:0s;visibility:hidden}.main-navigation.toggled .main-nav ul ul.toggled-on{position:relative;top:0;left:auto!important;right:auto!important;width:100%;pointer-events:auto;height:auto;opacity:1;display:block;visibility:visible;float:none}.main-navigation.toggled .menu-item-has-children .dropdown-menu-toggle{float:right}.mobile-menu-control-wrapper{display:none;margin-left:auto;align-items:center}.has-inline-mobile-toggle #site-navigation.toggled{margin-top:1.5em}.has-inline-mobile-toggle #site-navigation.has-active-search{margin-top:1.5em}.has-inline-mobile-toggle #site-navigation.has-active-search .nav-search-active{position:relative}.has-inline-mobile-toggle #site-navigation.has-active-search .navigation-search input{outline:auto}.nav-float-left .mobile-menu-control-wrapper{order:-10;margin-left:0;margin-right:auto;flex-direction:row-reverse}@media (max-width:768px){.hide-on-mobile{display:none!important}a,body,button,input,select,textarea{transition:all 0s ease-in-out}.inside-header{flex-direction:column;text-align:center}.site-header .header-widget{margin-top:1.5em;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center}.site-content{flex-direction:column}.container .site-content .content-area{width:auto}.is-left-sidebar.sidebar,.is-right-sidebar.sidebar{width:auto;order:initial}.is-left-sidebar+.is-right-sidebar .inside-right-sidebar{margin-top:0}.both-left .inside-left-sidebar,.both-left .inside-right-sidebar,.both-right .inside-left-sidebar,.both-right .inside-right-sidebar{margin-right:0;margin-left:0}#main{margin-left:0;margin-right:0}body:not(.no-sidebar) #main{margin-bottom:0}.alignleft,.alignright{float:none;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.comment .children{padding-left:10px;margin-left:0}.entry-meta{font-size:inherit}.entry-meta a{line-height:1.8em}}@media (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1024px){.hide-on-tablet{display:none!important}}@media (min-width:1025px){.hide-on-desktop{display:none!important}}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="HTTrack is an easy-to-use website mirror utility. It allows you to download a World Wide website from the Internet to a local directory,building recursively all structures, getting html, images, and other files from the server to your computer. Links are rebuiltrelatively so that you can freely browse to the local site (works with any browser). You can mirror several sites together so that you can jump from one toanother. You can, also, update an existing mirror site, or resume an interrupted download. The robot is fully configurable, with an integrated help" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="httrack, HTTRACK, HTTrack, winhttrack, WINHTTRACK, WinHTTrack, offline browser, web mirror utility, aspirateur web, surf offline, web capture, www mirror utility, browse offline, local  site builder, website mirroring, aspirateur www, internet grabber, capture de site web, internet tool, hors connexion, unix, dos, windows 95, windows 98, solaris, ibm580, AIX 4.0, HTS, HTGet, web aspirator, web aspirateur, libre, GPL, GNU, free software" />
    <title>Local index - HTTrack Website Copier</title>
  <!-- Mirror and index made by HTTrack Website Copier/3.49-2 [XR&CO'2014] -->
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--

body {
    margin: 0;  padding: 0;  margin-bottom: 15px;  margin-top: 8px;
    background: #77b;
}
body, td {
    font: 14px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

#subTitle {
    background: #000;  color: #fff;  padding: 4px;  font-weight: bold; 
    }

#siteNavigation a, #siteNavigation .current {
    font-weight: bold;  color: #448;
    }
#siteNavigation a:link    { text-decoration: none; }
#siteNavigation a:visited { text-decoration: none; }

#siteNavigation .current { background-color: #ccd; }

#siteNavigation a:hover   { text-decoration: none;  background-color: #fff;  color: #000; }
#siteNavigation a:active  { text-decoration: none;  background-color: #ccc; }


a:link    { text-decoration: underline;  color: #00f; }
a:visited { text-decoration: underline;  color: #000; }
a:hover   { text-decoration: underline;  color: #c00; }
a:active  { text-decoration: underline; }

#pageContent {
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;  padding-top: 20px;
    line-height: 1.65em;
    background-image: url(backblue.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    }

#pageContent, #siteNavigation {
    background-color: #ccd;
    }


.imgLeft  { float: left;   margin-right: 10px;  margin-bottom: 10px; }
.imgRight { float: right;  margin-left: 10px;   margin-bottom: 10px; }

hr { height: 1px;  color: #000;  background-color: #000;  margin-bottom: 15px; }

h1 { margin: 0;  font-weight: bold;  font-size: 2em; }
h2 { margin: 0;  font-weight: bold;  font-size: 1.6em; }
h3 { margin: 0;  font-weight: bold;  font-size: 1.3em; }
h4 { margin: 0;  font-weight: bold;  font-size: 1.18em; }

.blak { background-color: #000; }
.hide { display: none; }
.tableWidth { min-width: 400px; }

.tblRegular       { border-collapse: collapse; }
.tblRegular td    { padding: 6px;  background-image: url(fade.gif);  border: 2px solid #99c; }
.tblHeaderColor, .tblHeaderColor td { background: #99c; }
.tblNoBorder td   { border: 0; }


// -->
</style>

</head>

<table width="76%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" class="tableWidth">
    <tr>
    <td id="subTitle">HTTrack Website Copier - Open Source offline browser</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="76%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableWidth">
<tr class="blak">
<td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6"> 
        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr> 
        <td id="pageContent"> 
<!-- ==================== End prologue ==================== -->

    <meta name="generator" content="HTTrack Website Copier/3.x">
    <TITLE>Local index - HTTrack</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1 ALIGN=Center>Index of locally available sites:</H1>
    <TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH="100%" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="0">
        <TR>
            <TD BACKGROUND="fade.gif">
                &middot;
                    <A HREF="factalwayz.com/index.html">
                        Home | Factalwayz
                    </A>        
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <BR>
    <BR>
    <BR>
    <H6 ALIGN="RIGHT">
    <I>Mirror and index made by HTTrack Website Copier [XR&amp;CO'2008]</I>
    </H6>
    <!-- Mirror and index made by HTTrack Website Copier/3.49-2 [XR&CO'2014] -->
    <!-- Thanks for using HTTrack Website Copier! -->
    <!-- meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=factalwayz.com/index.html" -->


<!-- ==================== Start epilogue ==================== -->
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="76%" border="0" align="center" valign="bottom" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td id="footer"><small>&copy; 2008 Xavier Roche & other contributors - Web Design: Leto Kauler.</small></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=factalwayz.com/index.html">` removes the page before we can see it

Comment: No space in my Chrome. Perhaps you are seeing the scrollbars?

Comment: I see a horizontal scroll bar with white space on right side. ( no additional css codes are added)